# How can design Angular 2 in a intranet communication with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, angular, rest, web

I am trying to create an architecture for a web app. We are planning to develop the front-end using Angular 2 + bootstrap and the DB will be SQL Server.

As per the requirement, this web app is accessible to an internal team only that means we have to keep it inside an intranet.

So my question is: how can we design the communication between the web app and the database? What component should I use for this? Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Angular is not like php which works on the server,It is only a client side framework so it cannot connect with database directly, You need to use a server to communicate with database and angular will communicate with that server through web apis

You can use node (widely used with angular) to achieve this.

So basically your web app will have a flow like

angular(client) to node(server) to database

https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

This is a one of the tutorials pops up first in google. but it connects with mongoDB as a database which you can change to sql server. If you have anyone that can help you with node it is real easy. if not, Then also there are bunch of tutorials available on the internet for the same.

Again it is not compulsory to go with node, You just need a server.

Comment: Thanks, Parth. How about Java technology instead of node ? if its java, what all are the technologies we need. like spring, spring BOOT ...

Comment: Sorry mate,I have little to none knowledge about java, So i cannot help you there.

Answer (score 0):

I know mystery thing to comunicate between WEB and Database. It is called backend.